# Integrating Particles.js with Nuxt 3

Tags: nuxt.js, particles.js

Hello fellow developers,

I'm currently working on a project using Nuxt 3 and I'm attempting to integrate Particles.js for some interactive particle animations on specific pages. However, despite thorough searching, I haven't been able to find any official documentation or guides on how to achieve this within the context of Nuxt 3.

I am not very clear how to use the Nuxt 3 plugins to be able to use them in the application

Right now im trying this methodology:

```
yarn add particles.js
```

In /plugins/particles.js

```
Import Vue from 'vue';
import Particles from 'particles.js';
Vue.use(Particles);
```

Configuring nuxt.config.ts

```
plugins: [
{ src: '~/plugins/particles.js', ssr: false }
]
```

Then implementing the particle div into my component, but im getting this error:

> ERROR  [warn] [nuxt] Plugin /Users/nicoalvarez/Desktop/Repositories/back-office/plugins/particles.js has no default export and will be ignored at build time. Add export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {}) to your plugin.

Comment: Have you tried this package for vue 3?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-particles

Answer (score 2):

Nuxt 3 came out with huge differences from Nuxt version 2. these codes you provided are from the previous version. applying particles is now easier than ever. (thanks to [Joepocalyptic](https://github.com/Joepocalyptic/nuxt-particles))
here are the steps:

**1. Install `nuxt-particles`:**

```
yarn add -D nuxt-particles
```

or whatever your favorite package manager is

**2. Add nuxt-particles to the modules section of nuxt.config.ts:**

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules: [
    // ...
    'nuxt-particles'
  ],
  // ...
})
```

with these two simple step you are all set and ready to use particles
now you have access to `<NuxtParticles></NuxtParticles>` tags

**USAGE:**

there are two ways to use particles using this module:

**(A) using external JSON particles configuration:**

you have to make a JSON file with your particles configuration in it and I recommend using public directory for placing your json file

```html
<template>
  <NuxtParticles
    id="tsparticles"
    url="/path/to/particles.json"
    @load="onLoad"
  ></NuxtParticles>
```

**(B) using internal particles configuration:**

```html
<NuxtParticles
    id="tsparticles"
    :options="options"
    @load="onLoad"
  ></NuxtParticles>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import type { Container } from 'tsparticles-engine'

const options = {
  // See https://particles.js.org/docs/interfaces/tsParticles_Engine.Options_Interfaces_IOptions.IOptions.html
}

const onLoad = (container: Container) => {
  // Do something with the container
  container.pause()
  setTimeout(() => container.play(), 2000)
}
</script>
```

here is an example:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtParticles
      id="tsparticles"
      :options="options"
      @load="onLoad"
    ></NuxtParticles>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import type { Container } from 'tsparticles-engine'

const options = {
  fullScreen: {
    enable: true,
    zIndex: -1
  },
  background: {
    color: {
      value: '#fff'
    }
  },
  particles: {
    color: {
      value: "#000"
    },
    links: {
      color: "#000",
      enable: true
    },
    move: {
      enable: true
    },
    number: {
      value: 100
    }
  }
}
const onLoad = (container: Container) => {
  // Do something with the container
  container.pause()
  setTimeout(() => container.play(), 2000)
}
</script>
```

here is the link to the documentation of nuxt-particles:

- https://github.com/Joepocalyptic/nuxt-particles
- https://nuxt-particles.joeypereira.dev/getting-started/setup